# How to transfer rows from database to JTable and update database with edit JTable Fields?

Tags: java, sql, database, swing, jtable

I am currently designing a Item Sales Form in Java. Below is how my database table looks like:

```
    productCode | productName | productWeight | productCost | price | stock | reorderPoint

    bioflu100g  | bioflu      | 100g          | 4           | 8     | 300   | 50
```

What I want to do is to have a Sales Form where I can add multiple products to a JTable or an array and assign how much quantity of it will be sold to the client.

```
    productName | price | quantity | amount
    bioflu      | 8     | 8        | 64
    cefalexin   | 30    | 3        | 90
    betadine    | 16    | 1        | 16
                     total amount  | 170
```

When I hit the save button, then all the products sold would automatically deduct the quantity to my stock count. It would update my inventory in the database.

I have found this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3494425/230513) over the internet:

```
public class RowAdder extends JFrame {

  final SimpleModel tableData = new SimpleModel();
  JTable table = new JTable(tableData);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    RowAdder ra = new RowAdder();
    ra.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    ra.setSize(400, 300);
    ra.setVisible(true);
  }

  public RowAdder() {
    final JTextField textField  = new JTextField();
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        tableData.addText(textField.getText());
        textField.setText("");
      }
    });
    add(textField, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  }

}
class SimpleModel extends AbstractTableModel {

  Vector textData = new Vector();

  public void addText(String text) {
    textData.addElement(text);
    fireTableDataChanged();
  }

  public int getRowCount() {
    return textData.size();
  }

  public int getColumnCount() {
    return 3;
  }

  public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
    return textData.elementAt(row);
  }
}
```

I am having a bit of problem understanding on how to make this code work so that I can update my database with the deduction of the sold items. How can I edit this code so that it updates my database?

Comment: @peeskillet these code is what I am trying to edit so that it will update my database once i hit save button.

Comment: Please don't just take code from the internet and say "how do I make this code make my program work?". Please try and understand how the code works, and ask if you don't understand something about the code (not just what does this code do). Also there is nothing in that code that shows any db interaction. Please make a _real_ attempt.

Comment: Read [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [Lesson on JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html)

Comment: `I have found these code over the internet:` - and the code won't help. Your custom TableModel will not work with a JTable. You first step is to learn how to display data in a JTable. Then the next step is to worry about loading the data from a database into your table. Finally you can start to worry about update the database with data from the table. Learn the basics first before doing more complex coding.

Comment: Moreover, the [terms of service](http://stackexchange.com/legal) require [attribution](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) of the [original code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3494425/230513).